# Ansible: How to find aggregated file size across inventory hosts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, subtotal

I'm able to find the total size of all the three files in variable `totalsize` on a single host as shown below.

**cat all.hosts**

```ini
[destnode]
myhost1
myhost2
myhost3
```

**cat myplay.yml**

```yaml
- name: "Play 1"
  hosts: "destnode"
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Fail if file size is greater than 2GB
      include_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/checkfilesize.yml"
      with_items:
        - "{{ source_file_new.splitlines() }}"
```

**cat checkfilesize.yml**

```yaml
- name: Check file size
  stat:
    path: "{{ item }}"
  register: file_size

- set_fact:
    totalsize: "{{ totalsize | default(0) |int + ( file_size.stat.size / 1024 / 1024 ) | int }}"

- debug:
    msg: "TOTALSIZE: {{ totalsize }}"
```

**To run:**

```bash
ansible-playbook -i all.hosts myplay.yml -e source_file_new="/tmp/file1.log\n/tmp/file1.log\n/tmp/file1.log"
```

The above play works fine and gets me the total sum of sizes of all the files mentioned in variable `source_file_new` on individual hosts.

My requirement is to get the total size of all the files from all the three(or more) hosts mention is `destnode` group.

So, if each file is 10 MB on each host, the current playbook prints 10+10+10=30MB on host1 and like wise on host2 and host3.

Instead, I wish to the the sum of all the sizes from all the hosts like below

`host1 (10+10+10) + host2 (10+10+10) + host3 (10+10+10) = 90MB`

Answer (score 1):

Extract the `totalsize` facts for each node in `destnode` from `hostvars` and sum them up.

In a nutshell, at the end of your current `checkfilesize.yml` task file, replace the debug task:

```yaml
- name: Show total size for all nodes
  vars:
    overall_size: "{{ groups['destnode'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'totalsize') 
      | map('int') | sum }}"
  debug:
    msg: "Total size for all nodes: {{ overall_size }}"
  run_once: true
```

If you need to reuse that value later, you can store it at once in a fact that will be set with the same value for all hosts:

```yaml
- name: Set overall size as fact for all hosts
  set_fact:
    overall_size: "{{ groups['destnode'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'totalsize') 
      | map('int') | sum }}"
  run_once: true

- name: Show the overall size (on result with same value for each host)
  debug:
    msg: "Total size for all nodes: {{ overall_size }} - (from {{ inventory_hostname }})"
```

As an alternative, you can replace `set_fact` with a variable declaration at play level.